# Safe substitute for OS X `rm`?

Tags: macos, trash, rm

I am used to having `rm` to alias something safer.

I have been using `osx-trash`, but once I upgrade to Ruby 1.9.2, this stops working.

I know about `trash-cli` from Python, but I would much prefer something that moves files to the Trash folder in OS X rather than another directory.

Does anyone have a good solution?

Comment: Please, don´t get used to an aliased `rm`, rather get used to `mv files/to/be/deleted ~/.Trash`. It´s safe *and* consistent across systems.

Comment: Asmus: You see that only works if your mac has only 1 partition. If you have another partition, moving to ~/.Trash is not really correct (my ~ partition is not big enough).

Comment: Well you should have mentioned in your question that you have multiple partitions!

Comment: disappearedng: well, I think `mv` is still your safest bet. You could easily create a new folder on your other partition called `Trash` (or however you like it) and then `mv` the files there. Once you´re sure they can be deleted, delete and recreate that complete folder.

Comment: and then you can just have ~/.Trash be a soft link to the Trash folder on the partition that has enough space

Answer (score 9):

For OSX, you can use [`safe-rm`](https://launchpad.net/safe-rm)

```
brew install safe-rm
```

You need to do an extra step to prefer it over default `rm` - add a symlink.

```
echo $PATH
```

For me, I have `/usr/local/bin:` first, the same dir as `safe-rm` install

Add symlink to `safe-rm`

```
ln -s /usr/local/bin/safe-rm /usr/local/bin/rm
```

To remove and restore the default `rm` you can remove the symlink `rm /usr/local/bin/rm`

The config file can be added at `/etc/safe-rm.conf`

e.g:

```
/private
/Applications
/Developer
/Library
/Network
/System
/Users
/Volumes
/test
```

Test with `rm -rf /test` it will deny delete from `safe-rm.conf`

Comment: might be good to add also `/` to list of paths which shouldn't be deleted to prevent classic rm -fr /

Answer (score 4):

[hasseg.org/trash](http://hasseg.org/trash/) is an Objective-C utility like [osx-trash](http://www.dribin.org/dave/osx-trash/).

I've written a shell function that doesn't overwrite files like `mv * ~/.Trash` would. It always moves items to the startup volume though.

```
trash() {
    for f in "$@"; do
        bn=$(basename "$f")
        while [ -e ~/.Trash/"$bn" ]; do
            bn="$bn $(date +%H.%M.%S %p)"
        done
        mv "$f" ~/.Trash/"$bn"
    done
}
```

Comment: Yeah I have more than 1 partition and I would want to keep the deleted files in the same partition rather than moving them across

Comment: I added links to two other utilities and another function. Each of them should keep the files on the same partition.

Answer (score 3):

### **Introduction (you can skip it)**

For me `rm -i` would be enough, because it prompts you before deleting any file. However, some extra security provided by `safe-rm` isn't a bad idea at all.

A simple `alias` like `rm=safe-rm -i` *could* be enough, however `rm -rf` would not work, because `-i` is overriden by `-f`.

So, we have to make sure that `-i` always come after `-f`!

---

### **My solution (3 steps):**

- Install safe-rm: `brew install safe-rm`

  You can still work with `rm`, but you have modify the `RM_BIN` in the next step
- Edit your `~/.profile` (or bash_profile or whatever), and put the following code snippet, (which contain an `alias` and a `function`):

  ```
  alias rm="rm_i"

  function rm_i(){
  RM_BIN=safe-rm # you can replace it with regular rm if you like

  args=""
  files=""
  argsDone=0 # to make sure arguments are before the files

  for var in "$@"
  do
      if [[ $var == \-* ]] ; then
          if [ $argsDone -eq 1 ] ; then
              $RM_BIN # just to show the usage of rm
              return
          fi
          args+=" $var"
      else
          argsDone=1
          files+=" $var"
      fi
  done

  args+=" -i" # Put -i at the end (so rm -rf will not ignore it)

  $RM_BIN $args $files
  }
  ```
- **Finally**, `logout` and `login`, so the updates in the .profile are applied. **DON'T** use it before a logout/login!

---

### **Notes:**

- It can be applied to any Linux distro, with slight modifications.
- It does NOT move your staff to thrash. It just asks you before deleting each file!
- It works with `-rf` and with regexes.
- If you really want to use `rm -rf` **WITHOUT** being asked for every single file/folder you can still use `/bin/rm -rf` (or `safe-rm -rf` if you had installed it).
- **No more unintentional** `rm -rf` **or** `rm *` ;)